# grabbing value from html by xpath in python

Tags: python, html, xpath

I want to use xpath for grabbing `WhatIwant` phrase:

```
a="<b>AAA:</b> BBB<br/><br/><img src='line.gif' /><br/><br/><b><font size='2'>Text: </b>WahtIwant</font><br/><center>"
```

I want to grab `WahtIwant` from a:

```
tree=html.fromstring(a)
tree.xpath('//font[@size="2"]/text()')
['Text: ']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) and `tail` property (text that directly follows the element) of the element.

```
>>> import lxml.html
>>> 
>>> a = "<b>AAA:</b> BBB<br/><br/><img src='line.gif' /><br/><br/><b><font size='2'>Text: </b>WahtIwant</font><br/><center>"
>>> root = lxml.html.fromstring(a)
>>> [x.tail for x in root.xpath('//font[@size="2"]/parent::b')]
['WahtIwant']
```

Answer (score 1):

In xpath point of view, the text you want is *following-sibling* of the `<b>` element that is parent of `font[@size="2"]` :

```
tree.xpath('//font[@size="2"]/parent::b/following-sibling::text()')
```

or, you can use xpath that select `<b>` element having child `font` with `size` attribute equals `2`, and then select `text` node following that `<b>` :

```
tree.xpath('//b[font/@size="2"]/following-sibling::text()')
```